# In calculations with uncertainty principle why could you equate the uncertainty in momentum with the actual momentum of the system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

[This website](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html#c3) is trying to calculate the confinement energy of a electron starting from the uncertainty principle, but it does this: $\Delta p=p$. Why is this valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The electron is stuck to the atom, which isn't going anywhere. This means that $\langle p \rangle = 0$. The uncertainty $\Delta p$ measures the RMS fluctuation of the momentum:

$$
\Delta p^2 = \langle p^2 - \langle p \rangle^2 \rangle = \langle p^2 \rangle
$$

Since $E = p^2 / 2m$, this means that

$$
\langle E \rangle = \frac{\Delta p^2}{2m}
$$

The article you linked to is being fast and loose in going back and forth between operators and their expectation values. It's correct to say that

$$
\Delta p = \sqrt{\langle p^2 \rangle}
$$

but this is not equal to $\langle |p| \rangle$ in general:

$$
\langle p^2 \rangle \neq \langle |p| \rangle^2
$$

The article gets away with it since it is only after a calculation of $\langle E \rangle$, which involves $\langle p \rangle^2$ and not $\langle |p| \rangle$.